# PHP error acceder campo objeto

Tags: php, json

Tengo un fichero JSON.

```
{
    "tecba18a-rrpe": { 
         "a10_partition": [
                    {
                        "partition": {
                            "a10-url": "/axapi/v3/partition/BSS_CRC",
                            "application-type": "adc",
                            "id": 4,
                            "partition-name": "BSS_CRC",
                            "uuid": "7a7d93d6-872d-11e7-8379-2384e5e347da"
                        }
                    },
                    .........
                ]
    }
}
```

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$A10_data = file_get_contents ($filename);
$A10_datos  = json_decode ($A10_data);

foreach ($A10_datos as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values->a10_partition as $partition=>$partition_value) {
        return $partition_value->partition-name;
    }
}
```

el problema que tengo es que no me deja acceder al campo "partition-name", lo identifica como una resta y devuelve NULL

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintaxis:

```
$partition_value->partition-name;
```

Se evalúa como:

```
$partition_value->partition - name;
```

Donde `name` se espera que sea una constante definida (*en el caso de no estar definida, deberías estar recibiendo un mensaje de advertencia al respecto*)

La sintaxis correcta sería:

```
$partition_value->{'partition-name'};
```

Aún así, no vas a obtener dicho valor ya que lo que buscas se encuentra en:

```
$partition_value->partition->{'partition-name'};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso es lo que buscaba